# Get Result of New Function to variable

Tags: javascript, function

I made the following logic which is seem to be wrong

```js
function test() {
  return 'hello';
}

function getFn(whichFn) {
  var Fn = new Function(whichFn);
  return (Fn());
}
var testResult = getFn('test()');
console.log(testResult);
```

I expect the output of 'hello' but I am getting undefined instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return window[whichFn].call();` instead, and don't pass the function call parentheses to `getFn`:

```js
function test() {
  return 'hello';
}

function getFn(whichFn) {
  return window[whichFn].call();
}

var testResult = getFn('test');
console.log(testResult);
```

Comment: This is only working in this example because function test is nested directly in window. You should not use this suggestion for a general solution.

Comment: The example can be modified to suit any circumstance. We can only work on the information given by the OP, so I'd love to hear why you tell them not to use this suggestion as a general solution? It works for the given parameters in the question. If `test()` is not in the global scope, `getFn()` should be modified, but we can't second-guess that.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong (in most cases) but I would avoid referencing window in this situations. OP did for example not say that he uses javascript in browser. Maybe he is running javascript in console and no window is present.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 'test()'
> ```

Your function has no `return` statement, so it always returns `undefined`.

```js
function test() {
  return 'hello';
}

function getFn(whichFn) {
  var Fn = new Function(whichFn);
  return (Fn());
}
var testResult = getFn('return test()');
console.log(testResult);
```

Don't do this though. Generating functions from strings is almost always a solution to a problem better solved with a closure or a variable:

```js
function test() {
  return 'hello';
}

function getFn(whichFn) {
  return window[whichFn]();
}
var testResult = getFn('test');
console.log(testResult);
```

Comment: The second suggestion window[whichFn] is only working in this example because function test is nested directly in window. You should not use this suggestion for a general solution.

Comment: The OP's attempted approach (fixed in the first suggestion) also only works because function test is nested directly in window. `eval` loves its globals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function test() {
return 'hello';
}
function getFn(whichFn) {
    var Fn = new Function(whichFn);
    return (Fn());
}
var testResult = getFn('return test()');
console.log(testResult);
```

Answer (score -1):

@killair Hey man, I went ahead and remodified it to ES6

```
const test = () => {
  return 'it works';
}
const getFn = (whichFn) => {
    return whichFn();
}
var testResult = getFn(test);
console.log(testResult);
```